# Python: Populate column in data frame with a value that depends on the previous value

Tags: python, dataframe, shift, rolling-computation

i need to find a concise way to populate my dataframe with code like the following:

```
x = 1
df.at[x,'col2']=df.at[x,'col1'] + df.at[x-1,'col2']
x = 2
df.at[x,'col2']=df.at[x,'col1'] + df.at[x-1,'col2']
x = 3
df.at[x,'col2']=df.at[x,'col1'] + df.at[x-1,'col2']
x = 4
df.at[x,'col2']=df.at[x,'col1'] + df.at[x-1,'col2']
```

... and so on til the final rows.
Each line of code depends on the result of the one above so I am not sure if it can use the rolling function? I have also tried `.shift(1)` but haven't been successful either.
Basically I need to compute this above from x=1 to x=last column

Take the following as an example:

```
       col1         col2
0       0             0
1       1           value above (0) plus value from col1 (1) = 1
2       3           value above (1) plus value from col1 (3) = 4
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: How the final dataframe should look like? Provide example please.

Comment: Can you give an example of your original dataframe and what your final dataframe should look like? I think i get what you are doing but not able to visualize clearly

Comment: ``df.col2 = df.col1 + df.col2.shift(-1)`` ?

Comment: @Kate Pace, if `col1` values were `[5,6,7,8]`, are you expecting `col2` values to be `[5,11,18,25]`. ?

Comment: what happens on the first row when x =0 and so df.at[0 - 1, 'col2'] is thrown?

Comment: Edited my question above with an example of how I need the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution, it could be made better by making it generic (this is specific to the question)

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df,"\n\n")
x = len(df)
df.iloc[1:,1] = df.iloc[1:x,0].values + df.iloc[0:x-1,1].values

print(df)
```

I used .values to get a round the problem of the index giving NaNs and was helped by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618911/sum-up-two-pandas-dataframes-with-different-indexes-element-by-element) which ran into the same problems.

This returns,

```
   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6 


   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     2     6
2     3     8
```

Comment: Does this code still work if the initial dataframe doesn't have the 5 and 6 and its just blank?

Comment: do you mean blank or do you mean values of zero?  (Try it and see, btw).  If you mean blank, you _really_ mean NaN.  In that case you would need to set Nan to zero before applying the code.  see ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606274/treating-nan-as-zero-in-arithmetic-operations (a bit of mission creep on your part here, btw)